# Internal storage default

Tags: android, storage, internal

Do you have any ideea where it save the image on the phone ? The exactly folder ? :

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("name.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be somewhere in `/system/data/apps/your.app.package`, anyway find a directory named as your app package and it will be in there somewhere.

Comment: Do you have any ideea how to save in : Myfolders/MyNameFolder/myphoto.jpg?

Comment: how can i see from the phone where it's installed my app ?

Comment: Use getExternalStorage() to save in a folder on SD card.

Answer (score 0):

They will be in

```
/data/data/your.app.package/files/
```

And you will need a rooted device and something like ES File Explorer with root permissions to see them outside of your app.

Comment: Then how did i should save ,  create a folder (somewhere i can acces the picture ) and  save ? For example ,  on the phone : Myfolders/Mypicture/..   .   I don't want to be on sd card .

Comment: Here are your options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html I would use external storage for this. This may or may not be an SD card depending on the device. It's perfectly fine.